# Adding keydown to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit**

In my word game there is a grid with 3 letter words.

The aim of the game is to spell the words by clicking on the corresponding letters on the side.

When an area in the grid is highlighted it indicates to the user the word to spell. The user clicks the letters on the side of the grid and they move to the highlighted area.

When a letter is clicked it will animate to the corresponding area in the grid. I want to make it as user friendly as possible so I want to add "keyDown()" additionally so that when the user presses "a" it animates on the screen.

The letters are stored in the HTML like this

```
<div class="tiles-wrapper">

        <div id="drag1" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles2" tabindex="0" data-letter="a">
        <p>a</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag2" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="b">
        <p>b</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag3" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="c">
        <p>c</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag4" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="d">
        <p>d</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag5" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles2" tabindex="0" data-letter="e">
        <p>e</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag6" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="f">
        <p>f</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag7" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="g">
        <p>g</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag8" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="h">
        <p>h</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag9" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles2" tabindex="0" data-letter="i">
        <p>i</p>
        </div>

         <div id="drag10" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="j">
        <p>j</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag11" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="k">
        <p>k</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag12" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="l">
        <p>l</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag13" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="m">
        <p>m</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag14" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="n">
        <p>n</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag15" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles2" tabindex="0" data-letter="o">
        <p>o</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag16" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="p">
        <p>p</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag17" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="q">
        <p>q</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag18" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="r">
        <p>r</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag19" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="s">
        <p>s</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag20" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="t">
        <p>t</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag21" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles2" tabindex="0" data-letter="u">
        <p>u</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag22" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="v">
        <p>v</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag23" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="w">
        <p>w</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag24" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="x">
        <p>x</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag25" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="y">
        <p>y</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag26" class="drag ui-widget-content player-tiles" tabindex="0" data-letter="z">
        <p>z</p>
        </div>
```

I have have some of the script but I don't know how to link it up

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){  

        if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {  
              animateDrag(String.fromCharCode(e.which));  
    } 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/88/

Comment: your fiddle only shows a button, when pressed nothing happens..

Comment: Sorry mate check edit @Nelson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by triggering a `click` event on the appropiate letter div, like so:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){ 
            if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {  
                  letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                  $(".drag[data-letter='"+letter+"']").trigger('click');
            }

});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/92/)

Comment: That great nelson thanks. I don't suppose you could tell me why the class complete-word isn't applied to right place @Nelson

Comment: That's kind of offtopic, you should open another answerc, anyway I search the fiddle for 'complete' string and didn't find any match, you don't have anything called 'complete' in the fiddle you posted.

Comment: I meant to say right-word. I want it to be added to the <td> @Nelson

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function() {
   $('div.player-tiles, div.player-tiles2').keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {  
          animateDrag(String.fromCharCode(e.which));  
      } 
   })
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't just give code but also some explanation to the code.